# How to handle Permission denied on source command?

Tags: command-line, permissions, file-permissions, environment-variables

I am trying to persist my java environment variables to the system and I'm having trouble with the following:

```
:$> source java.sh

-ksh: source: cannot create [Permission denied]
```

What is the issue?

Comment: what are the contents of the .sh?

Comment: export JRE_HOME=/usr/java/jre1.8.0_11export PATH=$PATH:$JRE_HOME/bin
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_11
export JAVA_PATH=$JAVA_HOME
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export GLASSFISH_HOME=/appl/GlassFish-3.1.2/glassfish3
export PATH=$PATH:$GLASSFISH_HOME/bin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming this is ksh88: ksh88 has no `source` command, use `. java.sh` instead.

You could add `alias source=.` to your ksh profile.

Your system must have a `source` command that's trying to do something else: what does `whence source` tell you?

Comment: bash: whence: command not found

Comment: sudo -s source ./java.sh 
this worked for me